# How to build a TCP pseudo header and related data for checksum verification in C and libpcap?

Tags: c, tcp, ip, checksum, libpcap

I'm trying to build up the proper data structure using a pseudo tcp header, tcp header, and tcp data to be sent to a check sum function to be verified. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong in my code. 
The following code is my function that builds up the data structure and then sends it to another function to be checked.

```
void print_inner_ip_header(const u_char* pkt_data, struct ip_header* header)
{
   switch(header->protocol)
   {
      case(ICMP):
      {
         print_icmp_header((struct icmp_header*)(pkt_data+ETHERNET_HEADER_SIZE+sizeof(struct ip_header)));
         break;
      }
      case(TCP):
      {
         struct pseudo_tcp_header ps_tcp_header;
         ps_tcp_header.source = header->source;
         ps_tcp_header.protocol = 6;
         ps_tcp_header.dest = header->dest;
         ps_tcp_header.reserved = 0;
         ps_tcp_header.tcp_size = htons(sizeof(struct tcp_header) + header->total_length - (header->length & 0x0F)*4);

         int len = sizeof(struct pseudo_tcp_header) + ps_tcp_header.tcp_size;
         u_short ps_tcp[len];

         memcpy(ps_tcp, &ps_tcp_header, sizeof(struct pseudo_tcp_header));
         memcpy(ps_tcp+sizeof(struct pseudo_tcp_header), (pkt_data+ETHERNET_HEADER_SIZE+sizeof(struct ip_header)), ps_tcp_header.tcp_size);

         print_tcp_header(pkt_data, (struct tcp_header*)(pkt_data+ETHERNET_HEADER_SIZE+sizeof(struct ip_header)), ps_tcp, len);
         break;
      }
      case(UDP):
      {
         print_udp_header((struct udp_header*)(pkt_data+ETHERNET_HEADER_SIZE+sizeof(struct ip_header)));
         break;
      }
      default:
      {
         break;
      }
   }
}


void print_tcp_header(const u_char* pkt_data, const struct tcp_header* header, u_short* ps_tcp, int len)
{
   u_short checksum = header->checksum;
   int check = in_cksum((unsigned short *)ps_tcp, len);
   char* checksum_str = "Correct";

   printf("CHECK VALUE: %d", check);
   if(check)
   {
      checksum_str = "Incorrect";
   }

   printf("\n\tTCP Header");
   printf("\n\t\tSource Port: %d", ntohs(header->source_port));
   printf("\n\t\tDestination Port: %d", ntohs(header->dest_port));
   printf("\n\t\tSequence Number: %u", ntohl(header->seq_num));
   printf("\n\t\tACK Number: %u", ntohl(header->ack_num));
   print_tcp_header_flags(header->flags);
   printf("\n\t\tWindow Size: %d", ntohs(header->win_size));
    printf("\n\t\tChecksum: %s (%#x)\n", checksum_str, ntohs(checksum));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated because I've spent numerous hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,

edit: here is my pseudo header

```
struct pseudo_tcp_header
{
   struct in_addr source, dest;
   u_char reserved;
   u_char protocol;
   u_short tcp_size;
};
```

Comment: What is the actual problem ? How is your struct pseudo_tcp_header defined ? You'll have to take great care defining that so your compiler doesn't add padding, depending on how you use it .

Comment: I added in my pseudo header. How do I make sure my compiler doesn't add padding and what would it add padding to?

Comment: You print out sizeof(struct pseudo_tcp_header) and verify that it is the size you expect.

Comment: i verified the size and it is correct

Comment: btw the problem is that the checksum function never returns zero. a return value of zero indicates all the data is correct. i know the checksum function is correct becuase it was provided to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most fundamental problem I can see is the combination of:

```
     u_short ps_tcp[len];
```

with

```
     memcpy(ps_tcp+sizeof(struct pseudo_tcp_header), ...);
```

Adding to `ps_tcp` will add units of `sizeof(u_short)`, not bytes.

Comment: should i change that to u_char then?